# Run-time error 1004. Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following 2000 lines of code that get's a compile error because the procedure is overloaded:

```
Sheet7.Range("H2").Value = Sheet7.Range("H2").Value + Sheet7.Range("K2").Value
...
Sheet7.Range("H2001").Value = Sheet7.Range("H2001").Value + Sheet7.Range("K2001").Value
```

If I have, say, up to ten lines, it works. But I need the code to work for 2000 lines and that's when I get the compile error. To address the compile error, I used the following loop, but it gives me Run-time error 1004. Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

```
Dim RowNo as Integer
For RowNo = 2 to 2001 Step 1
    Range(Cells(RowNo, 8)).Value = Range(Cells(RowNo, 8)).Value + Range(Cells(RowNo, 11)).Value
Next RowNo
```

How do I make the loop work without getting a run-time error 1004?

Answer (score 4):

Change the line inside you loop into:

a) with full sheet references

```
Sheet7.Cells(RowNo, 8).Value = Sheet7.Cells(RowNo, 8).Value + Sheet7.Cells(RowNo, 11).Value
```

b) or shorter, without sheet references:

```
Cells(RowNo, 8).Value = Cells(RowNo, 8).Value + Cells(RowNo, 11).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

> Another possibility would be to use **array-formula**.

So you do not have to loop through all cells but instead let Excel to calculate it and return array with results. Code executes quicker than for-each loop. HTH

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Set range1 = Range("H2:H2001")

    Dim range2 As Range
    Set range2 = Range("K2:K2001")

    Dim result
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = "={0}+{1}"

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

    myFormula = VBA.Strings.Replace(myFormula, "{0}", range1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
    myFormula = VBA.Strings.Replace(myFormula, "{1}", range2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
    result = Application.Evaluate(myFormula)
    range1.Value = result

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the other suggestions but this one is the best because it accomplishes the task really fast. Processing is down to 1.98 seconds :-)

Comment: I'm happy it helped! Yes, array-formula calculated by Excel is faster then looping through cells ... much faster :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a helper column:

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet7
    .Range("I2:I2001").Formula = "=H2+K2"
    .Range("H2:H2001").Value = .Range("I2:I2001").Value
    .Range("I2:I2001").ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Ideally, you wouldn't want to hard code in your row references if it could be avoided. I also arbitrarily picked column I to be the helper column, you should adjust it to suit your sheet layout.

Answer (score 0):

eror  Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed
.
.
.
.

```
Sub kar()

Dim i, j

For i = 8 To 15

   For j = 9 To 15

    If (Range("ji") = Range("jj") And Range("gi") = "خريد" And Range("gj") = "فروش" And (Abs(Range("ki") - Range("kj") <= 50))) Then
     Range("ui") = -(Range("ki") - Range("kj")) * hi
     Range("uj") = -(Range("ki") - Range("kj")) * hj
     End If

     If (Range("ji") = Range("jj") And Range("gi") = "فروش" And Range("gj") = "خريد" And (Abs(Range("ki") - Range("kj")) <= 50)) Then
     Range("uj").Value = -(Range("ki") - Range("kj")) * hi
     Range("ui").Value = -(Range("ki") - Range("kj")) * hj
     End If

   Next j

Next i

End Sub
```